# Prove that any Hermitian Matrix is a real linear combination of Pauli operators

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, pauli-gates, linear-algebra

This is an important result in Quantum Computing because it means that the Hamiltonian of a Quantum System can be encoded as a sequence of real numbers and their corresponding Pauli Operator.

How do we prove this result?

(Note I am assuming that the Hermitian is of size $2^n \times 2^n$, and so by Pauli Operator I mean n-fold tensor products of the 2x2 Pauli Matrices)

Answer (score 2):

Consider an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix:
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{array}\right)
$$
What does it mean to impose that $M$ is Hermitian, $M=M^\dagger$?
$$
a=a^\star, b=c^\star,d=d^\star
$$
By that token, $a$ and $d$ are real and, if we write $c=x+iy$ for real $x,y$, then $b=x+iy$. Thus, we can write the matrix as
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & x-iy \\ x+iy & d \end{array}\right).
$$
You can readily verify that this is the same as
$$
\frac{a+d}{2}I+xX+yY+\frac{a-d}{2}Z.
$$
All four coefficients are real.

To think about the general case of $n$ qubits, realise that we can use a basis of $x\in\{0,1\}^n$. There are diagonal terms like
$$
a|x\rangle\langle x|
$$
which you can show how to construct from Paulis:
$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^n\frac{I+(-1)^{x_i}Z}{2}
$$
Then there are terms $(a+ib)|x\rangle\langle y|+(a-ib)|y\rangle\langle x|)$. For these, use the construction
$$
|0\rangle\langle 1|=\frac12(X+iY)
$$
for qubits $i$ where $x_i\neq y_i$, and the same construction as for the diagonal case whenever $x_i=y_i$. It should quickly be clear that we can use just tensor products of Paulis. It might take a little more care to be clear that the imaginary components all vanish.

Comment: Ah yes, I did mean the more general case! Will edit the question to make that clear. Sorry about that and thanks for the proof for the 2x2 case!